# How to clean black canvas shoes?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I have black canvas shoes. Every time I wash them with soap, after drying they become grey. There are whitish patches on the shoes that I suspect to be soap residue. But no matter how much I rinse them, the greyish patches won't go. Any suggestions to remove them after washing?

Comment: I don't understand "every time I wash them they become grey". Do they change back to black, or are they becoming less black each time you wash them? Perhaps you are washing out the dye. You could try dying them.

Comment: Do you mean using ordinary soap? In hard water that leaves a scum of calcium salts. Use a detergent.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use soap:

- Soap will leave a residue, especially if you aren't using distilled or rain water. Instead, use a mild dish detergent, such as *Dawn*.
- But unless the dirt is greasy, there's no need to use any kind of detergent or soap.

In most cases:

- Make sure the canvas is dry.
- Use a soft brush to loosen and remove the surface dirt.
- Use distilled water to rinse off any soil that remains.
- If necessary, use the brush with water, and then rinse again.

Answer (score -1):

Dish soap and a scrub brush, because if you put them in the washer then the colour will fade.